# Giving error on my searchbar after extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

After extending AppCompatActivity instead of Activity,  my project is giving the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:    Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   android.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)'
>   on a null object reference

and I followed this link[ this][1] but it did not work for me.

Please give me some suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

This is my code for search:

```
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

and this is menu xml

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/Search"/>
```

Comment: Like the other thread suggested, fix your menu.xml: use the custom namespace and support implementation, app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

Comment: Seems like you didn't follow the answer on the linked question.

Comment: When i write `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>` Eclipse give me error `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix` So i have to write android prefix before app.

Comment: Eclipse is old. You should switch to Android Studio as it would've suggested you to add this line `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` with a simple **Alt** + **enter**.

Comment: thanks @Sufian `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix` error is gone. After that, it is giving me null pointer execption on `searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));`

Comment: @AmanGupta You need to share **1.** the snippet where it is crashing, **2.** code where you're inflating the menu and **3.** your menu xml (which is inflated).

Comment: @Sufian please see edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94078/discussion-between-sufian-and-aman-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the custom app namespace for your **actionViewClass** too:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: When i write `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>`
Eclipse give me error
`Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`
So i have to write android prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change actionview class of searchview to support and change schema in menu. like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:titleCondensed="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Then in the code you have to get the searchview and use expand listent like this. Remember to use SearchView of support library.

```
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchItem);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(mContext.getString(R.string.search_messages));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(mSearchItem, new      MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It was my own implementation in one of my app so i shared the code rather sharing the ref link or so. :D let me see about its ref links and i will share.

Comment: No worries in that case.